# Unexpected value counts using awk

Tags: unix, awk, qsub

I have a text file called "test.txt" containing multiple lines with the fields separated by a semicolon. I'm trying to take the value of field3 > strip out everything but the numbers in the field > compare it to the value of field 3 in the previous line > if the value is unique, redirect the field 3 value and the difference between it and the last value to a file called "differences.txt".

so far, i have the following code:

```
awk -F';' '
BEGIN{d=0} {gsub(/^.*=/,"",$3); 
if(d>0 && $3-d>0){print $3,$3-d} d=$3}
' test.txt > differences.txt
```

This works absolutely fine when i try to run in the following text:

```
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222222;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222222;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222333;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222444;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222555;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222555;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222777;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222888;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
```

output, as expected:

```
111222333 111
111222444 111
111222555 111
111222777 222
111222888 111
```

however, when i try and run the following text in, i get completely different, unexpected numbers - I'm not sure if it's due to the increased length of the field or something??

test:

```
test=none;test=20170606;test=1111111111111111111;
test=none;test=20170606;test=2222222222222222222;
test=none;test=20170606;test=3333333333333333333;
test=none;test=20170606;test=4444444444444444444;
test=none;test=20170606;test=5555555555555555555;
test=none;test=20170606;test=5555555555555555555;
test=none;test=20170606;test=6666666666666666666;
test=none;test=20170606;test=7777777777777777777;
test=none;test=20170606;test=8888888888888888888;
test=none;test=20170606;test=9999999999999999999;
test=none;test=20170606;test=100000000000000000000;
test=none;test=20170606;test=11111111111111111111;
```

Output, with unexpected values:

```
2222222222222222222 1111111111111111168
3333333333333333333 1111111111111111168
4444444444444444444 1111111111111111168
5555555555555555555 1111111111111110656
6666666666666666666 1111111111111111680
7777777777777777777 1111111111111110656
8888888888888888888 1111111111111111680
9999999999999999999 1111111111111110656
100000000000000000000 90000000000000000000
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, as I'm obviously missing something... and it's driving me mental!!

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers in the second example input are too large.
Although the logic of the program is correct,
there's a loss of precision when doing computations with very large integers, such as `2222222222222222222 - 1111111111111111111` resulting in `1111111111111111168` instead of the expected `1111111111111111111`.

See a detailed explanation in [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Integer-Programming.html):

> As has been mentioned already, awk uses hardware double precision with 64-bit IEEE binary floating-point representation for numbers on most systems. A large integer like 9,007,199,254,740,997 has a binary representation that, although finite, is more than 53 bits long; it must also be rounded to 53 bits. The biggest integer that can be stored in a C double is usually the same as the largest possible value of a double. If your system double is an IEEE 64-bit double, this largest possible value is an integer and can be represented precisely. What more should one know about integers?
>
> If you want to know what is the largest integer, such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in 64-bit doubles without losing precision, then the answer is 2^53. The next representable number is the even number 2^53 + 2, meaning it is unlikely that you will be able to make gawk print 2^53 + 1 in integer format. The range of integers exactly representable by a 64-bit double is [-2^53, 2^53]. If you ever see an integer outside this range in awk using 64-bit doubles, you have reason to be very suspicious about the accuracy of the output.

As [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) pointed out in a comment,
you can have arbitrary-precision arithmetic if your Awk was compiled with MPFR support and you specify the `-M` flag.
For more details, see [15.3 Arbitrary-Precision Arithmetic Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#MPFR-features).